# Unable to install laravel on bitnami wamp

Tags: php, laravel, wamp, bitnami

I am totally new to laravel. I would like to use it in my project

I downloaded WAMP Stack 7.1.26-2 from http://bitnami.com and to my surprise,it already came with laravel pre-installed.

It is in the `frameworks` folder as in:`C:\Bitnami\wampstack-7.1.26-2\frameworks`

But my problem is that I do not kinow how to use laravel from there.It is not in the `htdocs` folder as I think it s supposed to be.

If I go to http://localhost I see only the bitnami welcome page

If i go to http://localhost/laravel ,it says **PAGE NOT FOUND**

I searched online for the answer but most of the time,it points me to this link:
https://docs.bitnami.com/google/apps/#laravel

But on that page, I see NOTHING relating to laravel.I cannot even find the word 'laravel' with a browser search.

If I run `composer create-project laravel/laravel myproject --prefer-dist` ,
I get this:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7601]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\o.o amoo>composer create-project laravel/laravel myproject --prefer-dist

PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/Bitnami/wampstack-
7.0.0RC7-/php/ext\php_solr.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
Installing laravel/laravel (v5.5.28)
  - Installing laravel/laravel (v5.5.28): Loading from cache
Created project in myproject
> @php -r "file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');"
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/Bitnami/wampstack-
7.0.0RC7-/php/ext\php_solr.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 73 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing symfony/thanks (v1.1.0): Loading from cache
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.10.0): Loading from cache

    Invalid zip file, retrying...
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.10.0): Loading from cache

    Invalid zip file, retrying...
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.10.0): Loading from cache
    Failed to download symfony/polyfill-ctype from dist: 'C:\Users\o.o amoo\
myproject\vendor/symfony/polyfill-ctype/4199a310f6ba3768faedee6d521ec615' is not a zi
p archive.
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing symfony/polyfill-ctype (v1.10.0): Cloning e3d8262452



  [RuntimeException]

  Failed to clone https://github.com/symfony/polyfill-ctype.git via https, ssh p
rotocols, aborting.


  - https://github.com/symfony/polyfill-ctype.git

    Cloning into 'C:\Users\o.o amoo\myproject\vendor\symfony\polyfill-ctype'...

    fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/symfony/polyfill-ctype.git/': Fa
iled to connect to github.com port 443: Timed out


  - git@github.com:symfony/polyfill-ctype.git

    Cloning into 'C:\Users\o.o amoo\myproject\vendor\symfony\polyfill-ctype'...

    ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: Connection timed out

    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.



    Please make sure you have the correct access rights

    and the repository exists.




create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--r
epository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no
-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vc
s] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<package>] [<dir
ectory>] [<version>]


C:\Users\o.o amoo>
```

That made me soo confused.It did make a project called `myproject` was made in : C:\Users\o.o amoo>
but laravel couldn't be installed???

If I try `php artisan serve` I get:

`Could  not open input file:artisan`

So with that,can I access `myproject` with laarvel if so,how?If not how come and what do I do?

Someone please point me in the right direction...

Thanks!!!

Comment: Have you seen all these error messages? To me, it looks like your system has no internet connection

Comment: But I posted on stackoverflow :-)

Comment: Obviously :) But as your system cannot connect to github, there must be some kind of connection problem

Comment: Oh right mayyybee but If so,how can install laravel

Comment: Using composer, but that will get you back to the first problem: why does your system throw these errors when downloading packages from github?

Comment: I dunno.......i dunno anything

Comment: Give me a sec...I think it is the wrong php version composer is using that's why

Comment: I think the problem is the proxy

Comment: Please reply.....:-(

Comment: If you think that you're using the wrong PHP version, or that a proxy is involved, how could someone help you?

Comment: I'm sorry.........:-(

Answer (score 0):

Alright let's start with why  your project is installed in C:/Users it's because you use --prefer-dist in `composer create-project laravel/laravel myproject --prefer-dist`.

> --prefer-dist: Reverse of --prefer-source, composer will install from dist if possible. This can speed up installs substantially on build
>   servers and other use cases where you typically do not run updates of
>   the vendors. It is also a way to circumvent problems with git if you
>   do not have a proper setup.

Second you run into errors maybe because you are in a directory that require additional rights, at least that's how it looks to me.

If you have installed Laravel correctly you should be able to navigate trough a terminal to the desired location, and either use `laravel new` BUT only if you are already in the directory that you want say `C:/Code/myproject` if you are still in `C/Code` you need to do `laravel new myproject`

If this doesn't work for you I would suggest you to verify that you installed everything according to the docs

And last but most important I want to mention 1 more thing for you, in Laravel it is really more convinient to use `Homestead`. You can read more for what is Homestead, how to install, configure and work with it here :
https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/homestead

Comment: Actually now when I read your question again, I also suggest you to ditch Bitnami for good. And go with a standart Homestead enviroment which you will grow to love. :)

Comment: Homestaed is too long to install

Comment: That's not true, also what OS are you using?